# Centering an h1 based on outside nav

Tags: html, css

I have an `h1` inside a nav that is currently centering based on the width of the `h1`. How would I use `text-align` so that the title is centered based on the width of the `nav`?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Big Caslon","Book Antiqua","Palatino Linotype",Georgia,serif;
}

h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
 
}

nav h1 {

text-align: center;
margin: 15px 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 55px;

  flex: 1 0 auto;


}
```

```html
<nav>
    <img class="logo" src="https://www.brachaprinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Apple-logo1.jpg">
    <h1> <a href="index.html"> The Novel Column </a> </h1>
</nav>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your nav to have a `position` of `relative` which means that any inside `absolute` element will be within the bounds of this element. Then set the h1 to have a `position` of `absolute` this will remove the element from the normal flow of the page and have it flow with the parent element with the `position` of `relative`. From there you can center it using `margin: 15px auto;`, `left: 0` and `right: 0` this will make the `h1` element 100% width of the nav thus centering it correctly.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Big Caslon","Book Antiqua","Palatino Linotype",Georgia,serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

nav h1 {
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  font-size: 44px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img class="logo" src="https://www.brachaprinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Apple-logo1.jpg">
  <h1> <a href="index.html"> The Novel Column </a> </h1>
</nav>
```

Now this method also has its fallback, you will lose the ability to click on the logo, but this can be remedied by setting a position of `relative` and `z-index: 2` so the logo element will be higher up than the `h1` making it clickable.

Comment: Not centering the element, it is as wide as the whole nav thanks to left/right:0 and absolute position. The text is only centered because of text-align: center; This is a bit of a hack as how will I click on the logo if it is a link? The title is on top...

Comment: That's my point, you are now making everything positioned and not relying on natural layout flow. Just posted my flexbox solution...

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is perfect approach, and you were nearly there.

I added an empty div with class `.ghost` to act as a counter balance to the logo. Since I know the logo is 90px wide I set the ghost div to the same, and both the ghost div and the logo get similar `flex` settings:

```
.logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 90px;
  flex: 0 0 90px; // same
}
.ghost {
  width: 90px;
  flex: 0 0 90px; // same
}
```

Now, with the `<h1>` allowed to grow (`flex: 1 0 auto`), it will take up all the rest of the space naturally and remain perfectly centered thanks to the ghost div flanking the right side.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Big Caslon", "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Georgia, serif;
}

h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 90px;
  flex: 0 0 90px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

nav h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 55px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.ghost {
  width: 90px;
  flex: 0 0 90px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img class="logo" src="https://www.brachaprinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Apple-logo1.jpg">
  <h1><a href="index.html">The Novel Column</a></h1>
  <div class="ghost"><!-- nothing here --></div>
</nav>
```